# Set the focus on input field - checkbox

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox on which I want to set the focus on, I tried

```
 this.renderer.selectRootElement('#checkbox3-0-abc').autofocus();
```

below is the element

```
<input _ngcontent-c16="" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3-0-abc" name="dm07d4535d9-5c02-48e9-b55b-82337bd528e5" value="false">
```

Above approach works for `type="text"` but not working on `type="checkbox"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this?

```
this.renderer.selectRootElement('#checkbox3-0-abc').focus();
```

OR
using this

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
```

Hope you are doing initializing after view is fully initialized.i.e. after ngAfterViewInit